# Plot colored points on grayscale (B/W) image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Is there a way to plot colored points (or rectangles) on a black and white image using OpenCV?
My image was typically created using `CV_8UC1`: it's a 8 bits `unsigned char` image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the image to colored image (e.g. 3 channels) first in order to draw and display colors.

```
Mat img_rgb(img_gray.size(), CV_8UC3);
cvtColor(img_gray, img_rgb, CV_GRAY2RGB);
```

See a similar question [openCV - draw color contours on greyscale image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441873/opencv-draw-color-contours-on-greyscale-image).